# Studying convergence of recursively defined sequence $a_1=2\text{,}\; a_{n+1}=2\sin(a_n)$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Firstly sorry for duplicate if this was asked before, i couldnt find.

This sequence is not monotone, but it seems convergent, i have plotted with Maple. Any hints to prove this is a Cauchy sequence? Or another method?

By the way, sequence seems divergent if i increase the factor 2. For example $a_1=2\text{,}\; a_{n+1}=2.25\cdot\sin(a_n)$ is divergent.

Thanks..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Over the interval $I=[2\sin 2,2]$ the function $f:I\to I$ given by $f(x)=2\sin(x)$ is a contraction, since $\left|f'(x)\right|\leq\frac{9}{10}$. It follows that your sequence is converging to the only root in $I$ of $2\sin(x)-x$ by the [Banach fixed point theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach_fixed-point_theorem).

Comment: As a remark, the divergence of the sequence $a_{n+1}=K\sin a_n$ for $K>2$ can be (at least in part) justified by the fact that, for larger $K$, the map $f(x)=K\sin x$ is not necessarily a contraction in a neighbourhood of its fixed point(s).

Comment: @πr8: I was tempted to add such remark to my answer, but there is no need now. Thanks, and (+1) back.

Answer (score 3):

**Hints:**

1. Show that $|a_n|\le2$ for all $n$
2. Show that if $a_n\to L, L=2\sin L$
3. Determine the stability of the fixed points of the map $x\to 2\sin x$
4. Deduce the convergence behaviour of $a_n$